# Get the coordinates of the nodes of a rendered graph in Sigma.js

Tags: data-visualization, sigma.js

Is it possible to get the coordinates of nodes of a graph after it's rendered by SigmaJS ?

```
var sigma = require('sigma');
var i,
    s,
    N = 100,
    E = 500,
    g = {
        nodes: [],
        edges: []
    };

// Generate a random graph:
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    g.nodes.push({
        id: 'n' + i,
        label: 'Node ' + i,
        x: Math.random(),
        y: Math.random(),
        size: Math.random(),
        color: '#666'
    });

for (i = 0; i < E; i++)
    g.edges.push({
        id: 'e' + i,
        source: 'n' + (Math.random() * N | 0),
        target: 'n' + (Math.random() * N | 0),
        size: Math.random(),
        color: '#ccc'
    });
sigma.renderers.def = sigma.renderers.canvas;
// Instantiate sigma:
s = new sigma({
    graph: g,
    container: document.getElementById('sigma-container'),
    type: 'canvas'
});
```

I want to get the real coordinates (`x`s and `y`s) of the nodes in this graph.
(After force atlas 2 is applied on it)

Answer (score 4):

You can get the real coordinates of the nodes on some events like 'clickNode' event. Here is the example code for getting the real coordinates on node click event.

```js
s.bind('clickNode', function(e) {
      console.log(e.data.captor);
      /* result : { x:-333,  y:-138,  clientX:363, clientY:262, ctrlKey:false,   isDragging:false, metaKey:false, shiftKey:false}  */
});
```

In argument 'e' passed in *clickNode* function, you can get data bounded to particular node as well as the data related to click event on canvas.

**Edit:**

Try using external json file and use sigma's external json parser *sigma.parsers.json.js*. This provides a callback function facility where you can get all real coordinates of the nodes. Find the below code.

```js
/*include plugins/sigma.parsers.json/sigma.parsers.json.js */
sigma.parsers.json('yourjsonfile.json', {
    container: 'sigma-container',
    type: 'canvas'
  },    
  function(s){       
    s.graph.nodes().forEach(function(s) {
    console.log(s); //result: "read_cam0:x" => x-coordinate ,"read_cam0:y" => y-coordinate      
  });}
);
```

Like in events, in callback you can get data about the node on canvas and data bounded to node.

Comment: Is it possible to get the coordinates without listening to an event ? e.g. by iterating over them. I want to use the layout and then render the graph using `svg`s and d3.js

Comment: Yes. Please find the edited content. May this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Two questions comes up for me : 1.What do you mean by "real" coordinates ? is it the same thing used in rendering ? 
2.Is it generally a good practice to use sigma as a layout engine ? aside from "ngraph" (which I haven't investigated yet) sigmajs has the largest number of layouts implemented. I want to be able to feed a graph into sigma.js and get the coordinate of the nodes and render it using svg. Is this a good practice ? and is it possible to define a specific layout to be used ?

Comment: First, the real coordinates means the actual coordinates of the nodes on the canvas according to canvas coordinate system after force directed layout completes. Second, in the latest sigma js version, there is an option to use svg to render the graph. Sorry, but I am not getting the specific layout thing. Can you please explain?

Comment: Thanks. In the code you provided where can I define sigma.js to use force directed layout ? or force atlas 2

Comment: You can add it in the callback function right before the forEach loop like this way :  `s.refresh();   s.startForceAtlas2();`